# How can we see closed questions?

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-questions

Where can we see the closed (or deleted) questions that we asked: I finally found the answer of a question I asked, but cannot find the question anymore on my profile, nor on the website.

Either it has been closed or deleted by someone, but I never had a warning (the question even had a positive score), or it got lost when I merged my two accounts (the first one was anonymous when I first used this website (this account asked the question), the second one was with my gmail log-in) which if this was the reason for the lost question could be more complicated.

Is there a way to be sure our question was closed or deleted?

I tagged this question as "bug" since it could be a possible bug of the system.

Comment: Closed but not deleted questions are listed in your profile.  I do not think that you can visit deleted questions (including your own questions) unless you have [reputation points ≥ 10,000](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: make this an answer Tsuyoshi ? so that the Community monster doesn't keep popping it up ?

Comment: @Suresh: I was not clear enough.  I am not completely sure about who can view deleted questions, and that was why I did not post it as an answer.

Comment: your "answer" is actually correct :). And on meta, we are more relaxed about answers in any case :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This is a more detailed version of my comment on the question.)

Closing and deletion are different notions.  (But some closed and even non-closed questions are deleted automatically.  See below.)

- Closed but not deleted questions are listed in your profile.
- Unless you have [reputation points ≥ 10,000](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) or you are a moderator, you cannot view deleted questions (including your own questions which have been deleted).

There is a [feature request on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) to allow a user to see his/her own questions which have been deleted, but this request was declined in June 2010.

#### Why are some closed (and even non-closed) questions deleted automatically?

If a question has no answers, low score, and no activity for a long time, it is deleted automatically.  Closed questions tend to have low score and low activity, and therefore I imagine that they are often subject to this automatic deletion mechanism.  See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81887/what-happens-to-unanswered-questions-from-deleted-accounts/82408#82408) for the gory details.

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65768/do-closed-questions-get-deleted-automatically-after-some-time) for another reason why closed questions may be deleted earlier than the automatic deletion kicks in.

Answer (score 3):

If you can provide some specifics, the mods can look into the problem, since we can see all deleted questions.

Comment: The question was about linear pogramming and complementary slackness, the only tag I used was "Linear programming" if I remember correctly. My login was gopi (but not with the same id). I asked it around april or may 2011 (28 of April iss my first login with this merged account, so it should be around this time).

Comment: I guess [this](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/6287/) is the question. It has -1 total vote. I don't know why it is deleted, the history does not say who has deleted the question.

Comment: we can undelete it at least. Gopi, is that what you need ?

Comment: Yes that was the one. It is just that I have the answer to my question and I think I remember there was one follower. More importantly I don't know if usually the history says who deletes the question, but there might be some kind of bug to check when two accounts are merged? Thanks anyway :).

Comment: @Kaveh: The question was probably deleted automatically because of low score and low activity.  Please see the update to my answer.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, it would contradict everything that is said on the meta about the questions being deleted only when offensive or spam (see [this question](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/619/deleting-down-voted-questions))

Comment: @Gopi: I wrote just facts.  The fact that I wrote about automatic deletion does not imply that I consider that automatic deletion is a good idea.

Comment: @Gopi: From what I found out, it is an intended functionality and not a bug.  Whether it is a good design or not is a separate issue.

Comment: ok the question has been undeleted.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, I was not saying you did, I am sorry if I was not clear, it was not a reproach. I was just surprised about it as a fact. I did not it was really a functionality of the website. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @SureshVenkat, thanks.

Comment: @Gopi: Oh, I see.  In fact, I am surprised, too.  Automatic deletion seems a little weird to me, but I do not have enough knowledge to make any judgement; for example, I do not know why this mechanism is there in the first place.  Probably there is some reason.